# In rails, how to query fields in join table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

In rails, I have two models, `:contest` and `:problem`. Each contest has many problems, and a problem can belong to many contests. A problem in different contests, may has differenet "index".

I use model `:contest_problem` to join `:contest` and `:problem`. In `:contest_problem`, I have a field `index`, to mark what's the "index" of problem in contest.

Now, when I execute `Contest.find(...).problems.find(...)` (`...` is contest_id or problem_id that I want to query), rails will create a sql query:

```
SELECT `problems`.*
    FROM `problems`
    INNER JOIN `contest_problems` ON `problems`.`id` = `contest_problems`.`problem_id`
    WHERE `contest_problems`.`contest_id` = 1 AND `problems`.`id` = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

I want to execute this sql query:

```
SELECT `problems`.*, `contest_problems`.`index`
    FROM `problems`
    INNER JOIN `contest_problems` ON `problems`.`id` = `contest_problems`.`problem_id`
    WHERE `contest_problems`.`contest_id` = 1 AND `problems`.`id` = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

How I should do in rails?

---

Models:

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contest_problems
  has_many :problems, through: :contest_problems
end

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contest_problems
  has_many :contests, through: :contest_problems
end

class ContestProblem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contest
  belongs_to :problem
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateContestProblems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contest_problems do |t|
      t.integer :contest_id
      t.integer :problem_id
      t.string  :index,     limit: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Problem.includes(:contests, :contest_ problems)
  .where(@problem.id)
  .where(contests: { id: @contest.id } ).first
```

This will give you, in one database query, the information that you need.